# What is the integral variable of a PIDF written as a digital biquad in transposed direct form 2?

Tags: control-system, pid-controller

I have a PIDF written as a digital biquad in transposed direct form 2.  Omitting the construction of the a and b constants the guts of the filter look like:

```
    // internal state for PID filter
    private double _d1, _d2;

    public double Update(double reference, double measured)
    {
        [... deleted details ...]

        // transposed direct form 2
        double u0 = b0 + _d1;
        u0  = Clamp(u0, MinOutput, MaxOutput);
        _d1 = b1 - a1 * u0 + _d2;
        _d2 = b2 - a2 * u0;

        return u0;
    }
```

I would like to turn the integrator into a Clegg integrator by zeroing the integration term on a zero-crossing.

Which of _d1 or _d2 are the integral or derivative terms, or is it more complicated than that?

Comment: I suggest implementing this in any interactive programming environment like a Jupyter notebook. Then you can very easily plot all the variables as they change, and see what resetting various things to zero would do :)

Comment: Well I've got it wired up inside of Kerbal Space Program and I tried zeroing out _d1 (which is what a certain Chat AI suggested very assertively would work) and that was incredibly poor.  I can zero both _d1 and _d2 and that knocks out both the integral and derivative terms on a crossing, which is what I went with.   After some playing around with it, adding a deadband seems to have been the most effective solution to quieting down the oscillations around the setpoint.